# Directus 8 thumbnail path not found

Tags: image, thumbnails, directus

Unable to generate thumbnails, broken icon, I tried everything (Directus 8.6.2)
The only thumbnail obtained is that of the collections list (24x24), which the development tools indicate in a subfolder "public /.../ assets /" which does not exist!
I don't understand how the thumbnails work in Directus 8 ...
URL rewriting ??

My Config file (default) :

```
'storage' => [
'adapt' => 'local',
'root' => 'public / uploads / [...] / originals',
'root_url' => '/ uploads / [...] / originals',
'thumb_root' => 'public / uploads / [...] / generated'
```

Would i have missed something?
Thank you.

Comment: Can Yoy try with leading `/` e.g. `'thumb_root' => '/public / uploads / [...] / generated'`?

Comment: I tried everything, too...

Comment: I just assume Your paths don't contain spaces around ` / ` and it is just an example. The correct paths shouldn't contain spaces (I don't believe Your folder names are ` public ` (notice a spaces around).

Comment: Of course (my example is misleading it is true). I use the default options, and that's why I don't understand ...